# How to implement authentication?

Tags: opa

I'm relatively new to Opa, but I've been keeping my eye on it for a while now. And I really like where it's going.

One thing that I can't get my head around is authentication in Opa.

1. How do I track if the current user is logged in/has specific privileges?
2. Are there any built-in validators for common stuff like email, etc.?
   ... and overall, what is the recommended way to build authentication with Opa?

I guess my bottom line question is: How would I approach to build an authentication like http://jetleague.com/ does?

Thanks,

-- Arthur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have answers for *all* of your questions but I think I can help on some.

1. I know that the built in module for doing login/authentication is `stdlib.components.login/CLogin`. I have asked here: http://forum.opalang.org/2_294, for details on how to use this. Reading the source was helpful (but not enough for me!): https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/blob/v2988/lib/stdlib/components/login/login.opa#L104
2. For email addresses, I have used the `stdlib.web.mail/Email` module. You can convert a string to an email address by using the `of_string` function:

   ```
   import stdlib.web.mail;
   email = Email.of_string("drwho@example.com")
   ```

But it is a bit of a bummer in that it'll crash if your string can't be parsed to an email address. You probably want to use the safer `of_string_opt` which returns `option(Email.email)` instead of just `Email.email`.

I will try to update this question once I figure out how to use the `CLogin` module!